# Make Custom class map with only one attribute as key

Tags: java, oop, hashmap

I have a class as follows -

```
public class Snake {
    private int head;
    private int tail;
    public Snake(int head, int tail) {
        super();
        this.head = head;
        this.tail = tail;
    }
}
```

I want to create a map of this class -

```
Map<Snake,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

But I want the key to be searched only on the basis of the head not both the head and tail. How should I implement this functionality?
I need this so that head, tail pair values where head is the same but tails are different can be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) use the Java senses of [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()). If you override those methods of `Object` in your `Snake` implementation such that they are based only on the value of `head`, then Snake instances will behave as equivalent Map keys (or Set members) as long as they have the same `head` value.

Note that this might be confusing behavior: You are telling Java that those objects should be considered equal in all senses regardless of the value of `tail`! This might be a good idea if `tail` is fixed and calculable based on `head` or some other value, but it might be a very bad idea if `tail` can reasonably vary between `Snake` instances that have the same `head`. You might instead choose to use an explicit key as Dilermando Lima suggests in his answer, or if the sense of equality is unique to the particular set or map, you might try a utility like Guava's [Equivalence](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html) that allows you to wrap your objects with a custom `equals` and `hashCode`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create some key logic to save on map

```java
public class Snake {
    private int head;
    private int tail;

    // create any key logic
    public String getKey(){
       return head + "-" + tail; // eg. with both but can be any other one
    }

    public Snake(int head, int tail) {
        super();
        this.head = head;
        this.tail = tail;
    }
}
```

Use map with key logic

```java
Map<String,Snake> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(snake.getKey(), snake );
```